# pdb repeat next command N times

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I'm trying to debug a for loop and want to see what's happening inside after it has run for a while. It iterates several thousand times and I'd want to check what's happening every hundred or so. Is there a way to tell pdb to run the next command a few hundred times so I can check quickly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is the `ignore` Parameter([Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)), which lets you skip `n` iterations.

Say you have code like this:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
for i in range(1000):
    pass
```

you could set a breakpoint with `b 3` to line 3.
Then ignore the first 100 steps with `ignore 1 100` (`1` is the number of the breakpoint) and then `c` to continue. Next stop will be after 100 iterations. If you want to pass the next 100 you have to write the ignore statement again.